# [Android]How to get item number(position) from a String[]

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a String[] that contains number of strings, what I'm trying to do is set a ProgressBar's progress according to which string is used.

For example, I have already determined number of strings and set max progress of progress bar accordingly; here is the list:

```
 "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine...."
```

..

```
 String[] cpu0freqslist = cpu0freqs.split("\\s");
 countcpu0 = cpu0freqslist.length;
```

..

```
 ProgressBar cpu0progbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
 cpu0progbar.setMax(countcpu0);
```

But now I need to set the progress of progressbar according to the item that is used, and I don't know how to get item position.

So if I want to set a progress bar to the position of item five (in this case it would be 6) how can I do that - how can I get the position of item five?

Comment: The "cpu0freqslist" variable is an array. So you can simple access that array with "cpu0freqslist[4]" for the fifth element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

essentially what you're looking for is a indexOf(...) ...

since arrays don't have it, you'll have to search thru it to find the desired string. so something like this (feel free to optimize)

```
 public int indexOfString(String searchString, String[] domain)
 {
     for(int i = 0; i < domain.length; i++)
        if(searchString.equals(domain[i]))
           return i;

     return -1;
 }
```

Then again, if you dynamically fetch your String[] data, it would be wiser to use an ArrayList and just invoke `list.indexOf(myString);`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Arrays` utility class:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"First", "Second", "Third"});
int index = list.indexOf("Second"); // 1
```

Answer (score 3):

`cpu0freqslist[5]`

Does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

Ok let me break your query into parts...

```
String[] arr = {"First","Second","Third"};   // String array with 3 elements

for(int i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++){

    int j = i ;                          // Position of the element

    String s = a[i] ;                    // Element Itself

   System.out.println("The "+i+" element is  "+s);


  }
```